# RailsTutorial - Testing - What to put for Database.YML for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, testing, rspec

First, thanks for your help.

As a noob, I've been happily chugging along this well-known tutorial:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top

and I'm caught in a section where I enter

rspec spec/

where I receive 2 errors. The 2 errors are in the format of

1. PagesController GET 'home' should be
   successful

   Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
   Mysql2::Error:Unknown database 'xyz.rb'

where "home" is the name of the action/page. The xyz.rb is the arbitrary
database name I have listed under the test section in database.yml. I
have already raked the database.

I'm pretty sure my problem has to do with how I'm not going with the
sqlite3 in the tutorial but instead with mysql2. The resources I have
managed to find only give guidance on what to input for the development
section in database.yml, but not for the rest of the sections like
"test". So, my question is, what exactly does this error mean, how to
fix it, and how should I configure my database.yml file? I tried
entering a file I see in my db folder like schema.rb, but this renders
the same error.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Set up another `sqlite` database, as is default with a new rails application, or
2. Create another MySQL database, the same way you set up your development database, with a different name (such as `test`) and use that for testing.

[Here's my database.yml file](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/rails-book/blob/master/config/database.yml#L12-16) from the Rails Tutorial that uses SQLite for *all* the databases; you should be able to copy the `test` section if you decide to go with #1 above.

Comment: IMO, you should not use Sqlite unless that is your deployment platform, or you simply cannot run MySql on your machine. The last thing you want to do is have your staging platform be different from development... unless you have a REALLY good reason to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @Brandon Tilley: I want to use MySQL because that is what I plan to deploy with in the future. I guess the question is then how do I create "another MySQL database". I'm pretty ignorant since I've been following the tutorial and don't know the inner workings of the whole system yet. As far as I know, the way I created my development database is by creating a model and then entering "rake db:migrate" in the terminal. So, what would it mean as you describe to use a different name (such as "test") since I haven't even specified the name nor which one I want for testing.